# Use windows proxy only for one, single address

Tags: windows, email, proxy, windows-10

My company only allows ssl email ports through their proxy address. I don't need for any other address either in email or when web browsing.

However, this proxy address does not work when I'm at home (my IP must be a company IP). So I find myself turning it on everyday at work, and off everyday at home.

Is there a way to set the Windows 10 network proxy to function (either) ONLY for the secure SSL email address I attach to, OR only when I'm on a certain network?

Comment: Is this your PC or your companies? Are you an admin on said PC?

Comment: This is the company notebook. I am the IT admin manager for my department, but do not control said firewall. I have no idea why they insist that port 465 go through the proxy, but it is as it is :D

Comment: I do have admin/root on all the PC and notebooks in this dept, including mine.

Comment: _Is there a way to set the Windows 10 network proxy to function (either) ONLY for the secure SSL email address I attach to_ -> no _OR only when I'm on a certain network?_ -> yes. Are you sure you need that?

Comment: *Are you sure you need that?* Not necessarily, if there's a better solution. What I would like to accomplish is NOT having to turn the proxy on every day (when at work) and then turn it off again everyday (when I get home with my laptop.) The ONLY address that I need to access via the proxy is **secure1xxx.redacteddomain.com** on port **465**. When at home, I have no internet when the proxy is on. Is there a better way?

Comment: I think it should be possible to use a [proxy auto-config file](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) to configure the machine to connect directly except to the one particular URL.

Comment: > Is there a way to set the Windows 10 network proxy to function (either) ONLY for the secure SSL email address I attach to
Have you tried configuring the proxy in your email client, rather than on the machine globally?